# Dynamic loading abstract factory

Tags: java, design-patterns, dynamic-class-loaders

I'm trying to create some variation of the abstract factory pattern.
The Factory is supposed to allow a plugin-like insertion of new implementation of concrete factories.

e.g.

```
public class AbstractFactory  
{  
  //some code here  
  public static void addNewImpl(String implName, /*class path or something else*/)  
  {  
    //dynamic class validity check  
    //save class somehow (db I guess)  
  }  

  public static getImpl(String name)
  {
    //is impl available  
    //return if valid  
  }  
}
```

I'm not sure I'm tackling the problem correctly or if I should reconsider my design.

Comment: Your abstract factory is not abstract, and doesn't compile. It's so empty that it's basically impossible (at least to me) if it's well designed or not.

Comment: I want to dynamically add concrete factory implementations. The code is just a general idea. I know it's not how the Abstract Factory should look like

Comment: @Stefan not using spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go ahead like this:

- get your code to compile :-)
- You need to define a factory interface which builds your target objects
- As your classes are typically loaded at application startup, it should be sufficient, that your DelegateFactory (you called it AbstractFactory) reads a properties file from the classpath at startup.
- For each entry in the properties file use the key as lokup and the class name as value of the entry.
- Sit back

Comment: I think I'll go with this solution. At what point should I replace this simple mechanism for a better one, like JPF?

Comment: I am not sure I can help with this decision, as I dont know anything about your requirements. I would think that the current solution should prove your concept. Probably when you want to allow the end client to pick and download additional components, you would have to rework the implementation. I have never sued JPF, but it seems to be an older and closed (with all advantages and disadvantaged) version of OSGI.